# resolve library and executable full path in libbpf

Tags: bcc-bpf, libbpf

BCC got BPF.find_library(library), BPF.find_exe(library) utilities to resolve and give full path. (not for given pid , not from /proc/pid/exe  , /prox/pid/maps (for lib)
I couldn't find equivalent public APIS in libbpf.
Found this static int resolve_full_path in libbf ,but can't use in product libbpf LPGL license.

Do we have to rollout our own?